How to correctly use enable_shared_from_this with io_context
I am trying to understand different scenarios of cyclic references while using ioContext and shared_ptr and I stumbled into this.
In the code below class Test has a member variable shared_ptr<io_context>. When I make a the lambda inside of function ioContext post inside of async_wait I pass shared_from_this() {which is Test} in it. Imagine now ioContext is running in a different thread so the lambda gets added to internal ioContext queue. According to my understanding the lambda goes inside of ioContext internal queue and now there is a cyclic reference Test --> ioContext --> lambda --> Test.
Is my understanding correct here ? Is there any way to avoid this ?
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/586afa794d15ef8f
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

std::string getTime()
{
    return std::string("[").append(to_iso_extended_string(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time())).append("] ");
}

class Test : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Test> {
public:
    Test(const std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context>& ioContext)
        : ioContext_(ioContext), timer_(*ioContext) {}

    void start() {
        std::cout << getTime() << "at start\n";
        timer_.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        timer_.async_wait([this, self=shared_from_this()](const boost::system::error_code& ec)
        {
            std::cout << getTime() << "Inside wait!\n";
            if (!ec) 
            {
                ioContext_->post([this, self=shared_from_this()]()
                {
                    printInPost();
                });
            }
        });
    }

    void printInPost() {
        std::cout << getTime() << "I get printed!\n";
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context> ioContext_;
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context> ioContext = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_context>();
    std::shared_ptr<Test> myTest = std::make_shared<Test>(ioContext);
    
    myTest->start();
    
    ioContext->run();
}


Designed way of avoiding cyclic references of std::shared_ptr is std::weak_ptr. I just use it whenever a question arises about possibility of cyclic reference. So weak_from_this is more idiomatic capture in my code.

@ÖöTiib i have thought on this but the only issue i have with using weak_ptr is it makes the code (especially the ones where there are nested async operations) difficult to read and ugly. So i was wondering if there is a better way we can couple shared_from_this with io_context without worrying about leak.

I don't know. It is ... if (auto self = weakself.lock()) else return; ... quite similar to Swift's ...
guard let self else { return } ... and Swift is IMHO doing it in most laconic way. Is it ugly and difficult to read?

Async operations aren't responsible for the lifetime of the execution context. You can simplify and correct as follows:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

static auto elapsedSeconds() {
    static auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    return (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start) / 1.s;
}
static int generateId() {
    static std::atomic_int id;
    return ++id;
}

struct Test : std::enable_shared_from_this<Test> {
    Test(asio::any_io_executor ex) : timer_(ex) {}

    void start() {
        trace() << "start" << std::endl;
        timer_.expires_after(3s);
        timer_.async_wait([this, self = shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code const& ec) {
            trace() << "Inside wait! (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
            if (!ec)
                post(timer_.get_executor(), [this, self] { printInPost(); });
        });
    }

  private:
    int const          id_ = generateId();
    asio::steady_timer timer_;

    void printInPost() const {
        trace() << "I get printed!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::ostream& trace() const {
        return std::cout << "id:" << id_ << " " << elapsedSeconds() << " ";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    {
        asio::io_context ioc;
        std::make_shared<Test>(ioc.get_executor())->start();
        ioc.run();
    }
    // look ma, decoupled!
    {
        asio::thread_pool ioc(4); // use 4 threads
        std::make_shared<Test>(ioc.get_executor())->start();
        ioc.join();
    }
}

Printing the expected:
id:1 0.000002 start    
id:1 3.000153 Inside wait! (Success)    
id:1 3.000226 I get printed!    
id:2 3.000516 start    
id:2 6.000720 Inside wait! (Success)    
id:2 6.000794 I get printed!

Backgrounds
Some detailed backgrounds, starting from Async Operations:
Instead, async operations are owned by the context. Async operations are initiated by initiation functions. All initiation functions enqueue at least one handler.
The handler is guaranteed to be invoked unless the context is stopped.
In our code, run() and join() only return when the context runs out of work, so after completion.
Destructing the execution context is safe when no threads are running the scheduler. The destructor will release all pending handlers.

UPDATE
To @Caleths comment, to ensure that a context doesn't complete, the holder of an executor can store a work_guard e.g. see make_work_guard. Also see more background than you will probably want

Allocation Guarantees
The same documentation page has good detail on this. Often, asynchronous operations are more stateful and might own temporary resources. The async completion model requires these resources be released before invocation of the completion handler:

If an asynchronous operation requires a temporary resource (such as memory, a file descriptor, or a thread), this resource is released before calling the completion handler.
[...]
By ensuring that resources are released before the completion handler runs, we avoid doubling the peak resource usage of the chain of operations

It follows handlers are dequeued before invocation.

I think you should be specific about requiring whatever is providing the executor being a long-lived object, rather than something that could result in dangling references.

@Caleth Do you have a concrete suggestion instead of the two sentences that I used to nail down both sides: (practical) "The handler is guaranteed to be invoked unless the context is stopped. In our code, run() and join() only return when the context runs out of work, so after completion."
(vs. systematic:) "Destructing the execution context is safe when no threads are running the scheduler. The destructor will release all pending handlers."

"is safe when no threads can issue new work" vs "is safe when no threads are running the scheduler". One might stash an executor somewhere, and in response to some independent stimulus queue more work.

Your fragment quote is about destructing the context, but I get your point. @Caleth updated with some extra notes

There is only a cycle until the io_context finishes that work. Once the task is finished, it is removed from the queue, and the last copy of the lambda will be destructed. This is desirable, as it ensures that the Test instance you are operating on remains alive as long as the task.
N.b. you don't need to capture this in the lambdas, self is also a pointer to the same object.
timer_.async_wait([self=shared_from_this()](const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    std::cout << getTime() << "Inside wait!\n";
    if (!ec) 
    {
        self->ioContext_->post([self]()
        {
            self->printInPost();
        });
    }
});


self is also a pointer to the same object and is more verbose in usage.

The issue i was thinking was if it happens now that the thread owning Test gets destroyed (for some reason) along with ioContext before the lambda gets executed and a new thread with new Test and ioContext is now made dynamically by the process running the threads there will be a memory leak as neither old ioContext and old Test would be destructed ? Is'nt it correct ?

@proton It would be undefined behaviour to destruct the io_context while there were still std::shared_ptrs to it, and running tasks. If you meant "release a shared_ptr" not "destroy", then yes, while there was pending work you'd have a leak. It would clean itself up eventually. If you want to be able to cancel work, you need to pass cancellation tokens around

@3CxEZiVlQ yes, boost does document that tasks are dequeued when completed.

sorry i meant release. On that note if the now shared_ptr to Test gets a new shared_ptr assigned to it and a new ioContext is also made before the old pending work is completed then the leak will be there until the process shutsdown or restarted. Is this then considered as wrong usage of ioContext or Is it so that shared_from_this should not be used with ioContext ?

@proton yes, it's somewhat strange to be releasing io_contexts. If you are, call stop on them first, as that will shutdown the work and release any pending completion handlers.

@Caleth When you say "... release any pending completion handlers" can you please elaborate (like does it remove the work from the internal queue?). My understanding is that io_context::stop() only prevents submission of new work so pending handlers that have already been queued will still remain in the queue? Is my understanding incorrect here ?

@proton it will release pending things too, e.g. if the timer has not elapsed, it will drop the outer lambda.

@Caleth but what if the timer is triggered and the io_context post call gets executed which adds the lambda to the internal queue and then the mishap happens and its left pending in the queue ?
Is it then just a better choice to have the member variable ioContext in class Test as boost::asio::io_context& instead of shared_ptrboost::asio::io_context ?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Never store the execution context. Pass executors nstead. Lifetime of the context is of not the responsibility of tasks.

@sehe is'nt the member variable ioContext_ in class Test serving as an executor aswell since it provides post method ? I can be wrong but can you please elaborate "Never store execution context...". How would we write the class Test so we would "Pass executors ..."
Do you suggest we should pass io_context to start()-->async_wait()--->lambda by value (in argument or capture) instead of storing it as member variable in Test?

Executors are small, cheaply copyable objects that can encapsulate more semantics on top of an execution context, and also decouple your execution context from the IO objects. I'll give your code sample a look

Posted my answer below
